# Time commitment to review very long article

Tags: peer-review, computer-science

I've been asked to review an 80 page article (63 pages + 15 page appendix, it's computer science). I've already sunk a lot of time into this, and am maybe 2/3rds of the way through. Luckily, it is a good article, and I'm learning new things, but it is just taking so much of my time, and as a result I don't want to check everything in detail.

How do you deal with reviewing long articles? Is it fine to not check everything in detail? What would you expect/hope from your reviewers when you submit a long article?

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, be transparent with the journal editor. Let them know how much you managed to do, especially if you decided that you couldn't afford been as thorough as you would have expected for a section of the document. Also, I think it's valid feedback to say that they have asked for a task that is beyond what you are willing to volunteer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you take the time you need to do a good job. Being fast but sloppy helps no one.

But you might also warn the editor that it is taking time due to the length.

Authors should expect that long articles, as well as complex ones, take time for adequate review.